# No such file or directory error using execvp

Tags: c, execvp

I wrote this program in order to use the `execvp` command and this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char **cmd;
    int i;

    if (argc == 1){

        fprintf(stdout, "No command inserted!\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }

    cmd = (char **) malloc( (argc + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    cmd[0] = (char *) malloc( strlen(argv[1] + 1 ) * sizeof(char) );
    strcpy(cmd[i], argv[i+1]);

    if (argc > 2){

        for (i = 1 ; i < argc - 1  ; i++ ){

            cmd[i] = (char *) malloc( strlen(argv[i+1] + 1 ) * sizeof(char) );
            strcpy(cmd[i], argv[i+1]);

        }

        cmd[argc] = NULL;
        execvp(cmd[0], cmd);

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed Execution or not existing command!!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    cmd[1] = NULL;

    execvp(cmd[0], cmd);

    fprintf(stderr, "Failed Execution or not existing command!!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return 0;
}
```

I run this program on the terminal using these commands
`./a.out ls` 
`./a.out who`
`./a.out ls -l`
`./a.out mkdir newdir`

The first two worked fine as well as the other commands without arguments. With the last two I get a `No such File or Directory` error in the terminal, but actually the `mkdir` command creates the directory newdir...
Can someone help me

Comment: You use `i` uninitialized in the call to `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're setting `cmd[argc] = NULL;` but that's too much by 1 (`argc` is the count of args with your command included). So `cmd[argc - 1]` isn't initialized (note that the loop above stops at `argc - 2`

You need to set `cmd[argc - 1]` to `NULL` instead or else another trash argument is passed to `execvp`, which explains for instance that `mkdir` works for the first argument, but fails when processing the garbage arg. All commands receive a garbage argument because of this shift.

You need an array of pointers of size `argc`, not `argc + 1` since the `a.out` command isn't considered.

Also, as noted in comments, you're using `i` not initialized at first, which work (since your `mkdir` command works) but out of luck (undefined behaviour)

A much simpler way to do it would be to copy the array of `argv` pointers (ignoring the first one which is your comment) without duplicating the memory for the string contents (since you're not modifying them).

```
   cmd = malloc( argc * sizeof(char *)); // argc because we need 1 slot for NULL termination
   for (i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
   {
     cmd[i] = argv[i+1];
   }
   cmd[i] = NULL;  // i is argc-1 now
```